# Regex Optional Capture Groups

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

The issue is to match something like hereunder

> hyundai E&C Hillstate (KOR) - Heungkuk life insurance pink spiders
>   (KOR)

Currently, the capture groups have been partially working although it stops when there is

> .*

The current regex expression is:

```
  (hyundai){0,1}\s*(E&C){0,1}\s*(hillstate){0,1}.*(Heungkuk){0,1}.*(invalid){0,1}.*`
```

Please assume that ignore case is in place. With the above, it will match like so

Group #1  Length: 7
hyundai

Group #2  Length: 3
E&C

Group #3  Length: 9
Hillstate

Group #4  Length: 0

Group #5  Length: 0

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Another case for would be

1. hyundai E&C Hillstate (KOR) v Heungkuk life insurance pink spiders (KOR)
2. hyundai E&C Hillstate v Heungkuk life insurance pink spiders
3. hyundai E&C Hillstate - Heungkuk life insurance pink spiders

The problem is that on my end we have something like hyundai E&C Hillstate v Heungkuk  and then that is broken up into pieces.

These pieces are then to be compared to a string that is provided by a 3rd party being like hyundai E&C Hillstate (KOR) - Heungkuk life insurance pink spiders (KOR). In which case it will be noted that it was matched or not.

Comment: Everything after the first `.*` is optional. Favorite match will therefor put everything into the greedy `.*`. Make your regexes "tighter".

Comment: @Yunnosch the OP *did* say the match is case insensitive

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ah, true. Was looking for the wrong wording. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `{0,1}` can be shortened down to just `?`.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add several examples of text to be matched, whith details of the output you expect.

Comment: @AdrianHHH at the moment this is the most complex case I encountered. I wanted to make it as generic as possible so that I can handle various eventualites.

Comment: All your regex parts are optional. That is not a good idea. Why not use `if (s.IndexOf("hyundai", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >=0) { /*hyundai is found!*/ }` ... and use the code for the other substrings? What is your final goal here? As you are not matching whole words, using regex does not seem appropriate, especially if you just check for the substring presence.

Comment: To understand your "generic" problem we need to see several examples. Also you need to explain which bits are constant, which bits are variable, which bits are optional, and so on. Your regex almost matches the one example you have given, but neither the regex nor the example explain what you really want.

Comment: All your examples start with `hyundai E&C Hillstate` and none contain `invalid`. So why does your regex allow `hyundai` and `E&C` and `Hillstate` to be optional? Why does your regex include `invalid`?

Comment: @AdrianHHH I was trying to think of an edge case. Where something was sent from my end that wasn't supplied on the 3rd parties side.

Comment: @Enzero But why would you want a match for those cases?

Comment: @Taemyr what I wanted was that 4 match whilst the last one doesn't. And therefore I could say that these 4 matched and the last didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this: 
`(hyundai){0,1}\s*(E&C){0,1}\s*(hillstate){0,1}\s*(\(KOR\)){0,1}\s*\W\s*(Heungkuk){0,1}(.*)`

Comment: Adding the country in the pattern is as arbitrary as converting `(Heungkuk)` to a required string. This would work too

Comment: I don't want to match (KOR). Moreover i added the "invalid" as it's possible that an invalid search term could be added,

Comment: Well, you have to do something with the "(KOR)" part. You can turn it into a non-capture group by prefixing the group with ?: and make them country-agnostic by replacing KOR with \w{3}, but you cant just ignore that section. So, you would end up with something like this: `(hyundai){0,1}\s*(E&C){0,1}\s*(hillstate){0,1}\s*(?:\(\w{3}\)){0,1}\s*\W\s*(Heungkuk){0,1}(.*)`

Comment: The issue is I won't know about the KOR part as it isn't always there.

Comment: If it isn't there, it wont be a problem. The regex to comments above will ignore it if it's missing - note the {0,1} behind it. However, if it *is* there, you will have to explicitly ignore it, in order to skip inluding it in subsequent capture groups.

Comment: I kind of played around with what you gave me and ended up with (hyundai){0,1}\s*(E&C){0,1}\s*(hillstate){0,1}\s*(?:\(\w{3}\)\s*\W)?(?:vs)?(?:v)?\s*(Heungkuk){0,1}\s*(invalid){0,1}(.*) this seems to handle all possible cases

Answer (score -1):

It seems that what you are looking for is named capture groups.  The syntax would be

```
(((?<hy>hyundai)|(?<Korea>\(KOR\))|(?<delimiter>(v|-))|(?<heung>Heungkuk)|(?<invalid>\S+?))(\s+|$))+
```

Inspecting the capture groups can then tell you if a word was included in the line, and gice you it's position as well as the name of the group that captured it.

Note that not all your keywords are included in the above.

You could also consider changing `(?<hy>hyundai)|(?<Korea>\(KOR\))` to `(?<hy>hyundai( (?<hy-country>\(KOR\)))?)` To insure that the `(KOR)` token does not occur indepenedtly.